# Google Web Designer Custom HTML5 Components

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, google-web-designer

How can I make custom Google Web Designer Components?

I was assuming they'd be like Adobe Flash Components. It's in Beta and I can't find much info on it all.

I've tried searching in all of the directories under `/Applications/Google Web Designer.app/Contents` to see if I could spy some samples. And the docs are geared towards users: https://support.google.com/webdesigner/

I want to build HTML5 ad Components the team can use.

Comment: Hang tight -- API documentation and code samples should be coming soon. :)

Comment: **To reviewers:** Due to my conflict of interest I skipped this question instead of voting to "keep open", but I do believe it's valid and would like to discuss it in chat if you disagree. Feel free to ping me to the JavaScript room or the Tavern. As my previous comment alluded to, this question *is* primarily about programming for a particular JavaScript API, for which documentation is expected soon. Thanks.

Comment: I found this after some digging: https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/6191694?hl=en&ref_topic=6175711&vid=1-635761907116760653-2556916812... It's a start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should create your own custom tags based on W3C standard
2. Create json manifest for your component:

   `{
      name: {string} A human readable name
      description: {string} A succinct but complete description of the component
      type: {string} The element type, which must contain a dash (-)
      version: {number} The version number, which must be incremented with each update 
      files: {Array.<FilesObject>} The JS and CSS files for the component
      externalScripts: {Array.<string>} The external script dependencies
      dependencies: {Array.<string>} The dependent types
      attributes: {Array.<Attribute>} The attributes of the component
      methods: {Array.<Method>} The methods of the component
      events: {Array.<Event>} The events dispatched by the component
      metrics: {Array.<MetricEvent>} Events that must be tracked as a metric
    }`
3. Create all the required .js and .css  then package the components.

In the following link you can find a tutorial on how to create custom components for GWD.

https://support.google.com/webdesigner/topic/6175711?hl=en&ref_topic=6175722&vid=1-635799099790786490-3463806884

Hope it helps.